# RecyclerView inside a RemoteView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, remoteview

Is there any way to set and update a RecyclerView inside a RemoteView?
I want to show a RecyclerView inside a notification. I already set the custom view inside a notification, but I'm unable to set data in the RecyclerView, see here:

```
// my playout passed here have a Recycler View
// How to findViewById there and set my data?
val contentView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_layout)
val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContent(contentView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you can't**. The notification has fixed max size, and even if you could send your custom RemoteView, there isn't option for using ListView or RecyclerView and filling them with Adapter.